# Confused by gdb print ptr vs print "%s"

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

```
1167      ptr = (void*)getcwd(cwd, MAX_PATH_LENGTH-1);
(gdb) n
1168      if (!ptr) {
(gdb) print ptr
$1 = 0xbff2d96c "/media/MMC-SD/partition1/aaaaaaaaaaa"
(gdb) print &cwd
$2 = (char (*)[3500]) 0xbff2d96c
(gdb) print strlen(cwd)
$3 = 36
(gdb) print "%s",cwd
$4 = "/media/MMC-SD/partition1/aaaaaaaaaaa", '\0' <repeats 912 times>, "��O�001\000\000\000\000��027\000\000\000�3����EL鷠3�000��027\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\027\000\000\000\000��/�027\000\000\000�3����N����\230���鷠3�000��027\000\000\000\000\000\000\000��000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000��M鷠3����\000\000\000\000.\231�027��w\005\b\001\000"...
(gdb) print "%s", ptr
$5 = 0xbff2d96c "/media/MMC-SD/partition1/aaaaaaaaaaa"
(gdb) Quit
```

Why is ptr printing the string correctly but cwd not; this also affects the program and it crashes if I try to use the cwd...

[edit: turns out that crash was caused by a stupid buffer overflow on this var... grr...not gdb, but the print question was still valid]

Comment: anybody care to edit the title so that it gives us more information?  I don't have the rep to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `cwd` is printed differently in `gdb` is because `gdb` knows that `ptr` is a `char *` (I guess) and that `cwd` is an array of length `3500` (as shown in your output). So when printing `ptr` it prints the pointer value (and as a service also the string it points to) and when printing `cwd` it prints the *whole* array.

I don't see any reason why using `cwd` instead of `ptr` would lead to problems, but I would need to see some code to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with mweerden. Trying something I believe is similar to your code, I get:

```
(gdb) print cwd
$1 = "/media", '\0' <repeats 782 times>, "\016���" ...
(gdb) print (char*) cwd
$2 = 0xbfc8eb84 "/media"
```

from gdb, so it seems that since `cwd` was defined as `char cwd[3500]`, gdb prints the entire array, while if you tell gdb to interpret it as a `char*`, it will work as you expect. If your application crashes, I would assume it is because of something else.

Answer (score 1):

That `ptr` is displayed as nicely-formatted string and `cwd` as "byte buffer" is probably specific to gdb. In any case it shouldn't affect your application; according to `man 3 getcwd`, `ptr` should point to `cwd` (or it should be NULL if an error occurred).
Can you use `ptr` without crashing the program?

Answer (score 0):

What type is cwd?  The above code snippet doesn't tell us that.  It could be that ptr being a void* is treated differently by gdb.